# DataTable's NewRow() method causes re-evaluation of LINQ expression after being used as a BindingSource with AsDataView()

Tags: vb.net, winforms, linq, dataview, bindingsource

In the following code, I have a LINQ expression that produces an `EnumerableRowCollection(Of DataRow)` that is eventually used in a `BindingSource.`

The first time the code loops, it's fine.  However, once the `BindingSource` for the first `Control` has been set using `AsDataView()` on the `IEnumerable`, the next time the `NewRow()` method on the `DataTable` is called, it re-evaluates the LINQ expression.

```
Option Explicit On
Option Infer Off
Option Strict On

Public Class Form1
    Dim ds As New DataSet()

    Private Sub Form1_Load( sender As Object,  e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ds.Tables.Add("Table1")

        Dim comparisonInteger As Integer = 12
        ds.Tables("Table1").Columns.Add("ID", GetType(Integer))
        ds.Tables("Table1").Columns.Add("IntegerValue", GetType(Integer))
        ds.Tables("Table1").Columns.Add("StringValue", GetType(String))

        ds.Tables("Table1").Rows.Add({1, 47, "row 1"})
        ds.Tables("Table1").Rows.Add({2, 2, "row 1"})
        ds.Tables("Table1").Rows.Add({3, 7, "row 1"})
        ds.Tables("Table1").Rows.Add({4, 6, "row 1"})

        For i As Integer = 0 To 2
            Dim iterator As Integer = i
            Dim tb As New TextBox()

            CreateNewRowIfMissing(comparisonInteger+i)

            Dim dataValue As EnumerableRowCollection(Of DataRow) =  ds.Tables("Table1").AsEnumerable() _
                                                                        .Where(Function(v) DirectCast(v("IntegerValue"), Integer) = comparisonInteger + iterator)

            Dim bs As New BindingSource(dataValue.AsDataView(), Nothing)
            Dim b As New Binding("Text", bs, "IntegerValue")
            b.DataSourceUpdateMode = DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged
            tb.DataBindings.Add(b)

            tb.Location = New Point(10, 10 * Me.Controls.Count+1)

            Me.Controls.Add(tb)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub CreateNewRowIfMissing(comparisonInteger As Integer)

        If  ds.Tables("Table1").AsEnumerable() _
                .Where(Function(v) DirectCast(v("IntegerValue"), Integer) = comparisonInteger) _
                .Count() = 0

            ds.Tables("Table1").Rows.Add(ds.Tables("Table1").NewRow()) 'Prompts the dataValue IEnumerable to begin evaluating again.
            ds.Tables("Table1").Rows(ds.Tables("Table1").Rows.Count-1)("ID") = ds.Tables("Table1").Rows.Count
            ds.Tables("Table1").Rows(ds.Tables("Table1").Rows.Count-1)("IntegerValue") = comparisonInteger
            ds.Tables("Table1").Rows(ds.Tables("Table1").Rows.Count-1)("StringValue") = "row" & ds.Tables("Table1").Rows.Count.ToString()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

To clarify, I used to use a standard `DataView` with a `RowFilter` as the `BindingSource`, which worked:

```
Dim dv As New DataView(ds.Tables("Table1"))
dv.RowFilter = "IntegerValue=" & (comparisonInteger+iteratorValue)
```

However I felt it might be nicer to make use of LINQ instead.

So, what's going on here?  Why is the LINQ expression the `DataView` was based on being re-evaluated on the call to the `DataTable`'s `NewRow()` method?  Is there any way I can prevent this?

I had hoped that `AsDataView()` would have produced a `DataView` that would behave in the same way as the above two lines.

As potential work-around, I've found that I can use this as the `BindingSource`'s `DataSource`:

`New DataView(dataValue.AsEnumerable().CopyToDataTable())`

However, I'm concerned about potential performance with such a line in the future, and that I might as well use the `DataView` with the `RowFilter` rather than the LINQ if it required the above line.

Answer (score 1):

It's the normal behavior of `DataTableExtensions.AsEnumerable()` and it's [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2):

> The enumerable object returned by the `AsEnumerable` method is
>   permanently bound to the DataTable that produced it. Multiple calls to
>   the `AsEnumerable` method will return multiple, independent queryable
>   objects that are all bound to the source `DataTable`.

Also the normal behavior of `DataView` which is also [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The `DataView` does not store data, but instead represents a connected
>   view of its corresponding DataTable.

When you call [`DataTable.AsEnumemarble()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data.DataSetExtensions/System/Data/DataTableExtensions.cs,234b3444d2a5ff75) method, the [`EnumerableRowCollection<DatRow>`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data.DataSetExtensions/System/Data/EnumerableRowCollection.cs) which returns by the method keeps a reference to the original `DataTable` and then use it each time you call [`EnumerableRowCollection(Of T).AsDataView()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data.DataSetExtensions/System/Data/DataTableExtensions.cs,8dca9be965589f25) method and returns rows of original `DataTable` which is used to create the collection.

So in your example `dataValue.AsDataView()` which you used as `DataSource` of the `BindingSource` always returns current rows of `DataTable` when a `ListChanged` event raised.

But if you assign `new DataView(data.AsEnumerable().CopyToDataTable())` to `DataSource` of the `BindingSource`, since you are using a different `DataTable` by calling `CopyToDataTable`, changing the original `DataTable` doesn't have any impact on the data source which is completely unaware of the original `DataTable`. In fact its enough to use below statement as `DataSource` of the `BindingSource`:

```
bs.DataSource = dataValue.CopyToDataTable()
```

**Example**

Put a `DataGridView` and 3 buttons on a `Form`, then handle `Click` event of buttons like below.

```cs
DataTable dt;
EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> data;
BindingSource bs;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("A", typeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        dt.Rows.Add(i);
    data = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<int>(0) >= 3);
    bs = new BindingSource();
    bs.DataSource = data.AsDataView(); 
    bs.RaiseListChangedEvents = true;  
    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
}
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dt.Rows.Add(dt.AsEnumerable().Max(x => x.Field<int>(0)) + 1);
}
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var row = data.Where(x => x.Field<int>(0) == 3).First();
    row[0] = 333;
    MessageBox.Show(dt.Rows[3][0].ToString());
}
```

**Test 1**

1. Click on `Button1`, the `DataGridView` will show 3, 4 in column `A`.
2. Click on `Button2`, new row with `5` as value of column `A` will be added and shown immediately in grid. Also it shows a `MessageBox` which shows `3` as count of items in `data`.
3. Click on `Button3`, 3 will be changed to `333` and immediately will be shown in grid. Also it shows `333` as value of cell in data table.

Result → by turning on `ListChanged` and using `AsDataView` you will see changes immediately in grid.

**Test 2**

1. Turn off raising `ListChanged` using `bs.RaiseListChangedEvents = false;`
2. Click on `Button1` will act like test 1.
3. Click on `Button2` will no more shows new record immediately. While it shows `3` as count of rows in `data`.
4. Click on `Button3` will no more shows edited value immediately. While the messagebox shows the data has been changed in `DataTable`.

Result → If you turn off ListChanged event, the changed will not be shown in the list immediately.

**Test 3**

1. Use `bs.DataSource = data.CopyToDataTable();`
2. Set `bs.RaiseListChangedEvents = true;`
3. Click on `Button1` to fill grid.
4. Click on `Button2` doesn't have any impact on grid, but shows 3 as number of rows.
5. Click on `Button3` doesn't have any impact on grid, but shows `333` as value of data table.

Result → `AsDataTable` creates a new `DataTable` which is not related to original `DataTable`.

Comment: Ah, so `CopyToDataTable` will most definitely break my DataBinding.  Probably should have tested that before considering it as an alternative.  Anyway, I do get that it's referencing the same table (which is what I want) under the `IEnumerable`.  Are you saying that when the `DataTable` has a new row added, this raises the `ListChanged` event in the `DataView`, which results in the re-evaluation of the linq expression that the `DataView` was created from?  Is my understanding of that correct?

Comment: *1)* The data that you receive using `CopyToDataTable` contains the same values, but it's another reference. It's a different `DataTable`.  *2)* `ListChanged` event of `DataView` will be raised  when you add a record or apply any changes to it's underlying `DataTable`. *3)* The `ListChanged` event of `DataView` cause the bound control ask about data and so the whole data including new rows will return to `DataGridView`. For example if you set `bs.RaiseListChangedEvents=false` you will not see changes in `DataGridView`.

Comment: Don't be worry about performance. Showing new records which added to `DataTable` doesn't have any negative impact on performance. Just think about your requirement and what you need. Then based on your requirement choose the solution. For example if you need data-binding to original records, you should use `AsDataView`. Also if you don't want to show new records (I've no idea about why) then apply a filter to `DataView.RowFilter`.

Comment: Regarding point 1, I know it's a different `DataTable`, that's why it would break my data binding (and also why I was concerned about performance, with the duplication of data, but that's now a moot point).  I'm not sure why you're suggesting `AsDataView()` as it's already in the question.  Setting `RaiseListChangedEvents` to `False` had no impact - the LINQ expression is still re-evaluated.  In addition after adding a handler to the `DataView` for the `ListChanged` event, I can see that the `ListChanged` event is never raised.  It must go to the LINQ directly.

Comment: I'm not sure why did you post wrong conclusion based on such a detailed answer. I just posted an example and some tests for you. You can find the results obviously and you will see the answer is completely correct. The answer contains some links to source code of classes on .Net Framework which you can follow. Also it contains links to documentations which confirms my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, your updated answer differs significantly from the scenario that I'm representing; there is no `DataGridView`.  Instead there are multiple dynamically-generated controls, each data-bound individually in a loop, on load.

Comment: I know that each call to `AsEnumerable()` returns an independent queryable object bound to the `DataTable`, and I know that a `DataView` on a `DataTable` does not contain the data, it merely points to it (an obvious example being the `DefaultView` property on the `DataTable` class).  However, your answer has been useful in highlighting the `LIstChanged` event which has pointed me in the right direction, hence my answer.  I do appreciate your tenacity however, and have up-voted accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like whenever the underlying `DataTable` is updated, the LINQ expression for the `DataView` is automatically re-evaluated.  This means that the LINQ was being re-evaluated when the new row was added to the `DataTable`, rather than on the call to `NewRow()`.  This wasn't immediately obvious to me as I was doing both actions in a single line: `ds.Tables("Table1").Rows.Add(ds.Tables("Table1").NewRow())`

@RezaAghaei mentioned that the `ListChanged` event will get raised if the underlying `DataTable` is updated.  Through testing, it seems that if the `DataView` is created from a LINQ expression, it re-valuates the LINQ *before* the `ListChanged` event is raised, if the underlying `DataTable` is updated.

As a consequence of this, setting the `BindingSource`'s `RaiseListChangedEvents` property won't stop the evaluation of the LINQ, and as the evaluation happens prior to the `ListChanged` event raised, there appears to be no other event that can be handled to cancel the behaviour, so I don't think it's possible to stop this from happening.

However, now that I understand what it's doing, it makes sense for the underlying LINQ expression to be re-evaluated when the row itself is added to the `DataTable`, so it probably wouldn't be a good idea to stop it anyway.

It was causing some bother for me though as the new row I was adding was not fully set-up, resulting in an `InvalidCastException`.  However, in my example above, I merely needed to make sure that the new row is fully set-up before adding it to the `DataTable`.  Thus, when the LINQ is re-evaluated, the row contains valid data and the expression runs without error.

So, in the example above, the `CreateNewRowIfMissing()` method merely needs to be adjusted to the following:

```
Private Sub CreateNewRowIfMissing(comparisonInteger As Integer)

    If  ds.Tables("Table1").AsEnumerable() _
            .Where(Function(v) DirectCast(v("IntegerValue"), Integer) = comparisonInteger) _
            .Count() = 0

        Dim newRow As DataRow = ds.Tables("Table1").NewRow()

        newRow("ID") = ds.Tables("Table1").Rows.Count
        newRow("IntegerValue") = comparisonInteger
        newRow("StringValue") = "row" & ds.Tables("Table1").Rows.Count.ToString()

        ds.Tables("Table1").Rows.Add(newRow) 'Prompts the dataValue IEnumerable to begin evaluating again.
    End If
End Sub
```

This ensures that the new row is only added to the `DataTable` after it is ready and contains valid data.  As  result, when it is finally added, the LINQ expression re-evaluates and doesn't throw an `InvalidCastException`.

Comment: **•** It's not clear what kind of test cause you think `ListChanged` event will not raise if you add record to `DataTable`→Wrong! it will be raised.  **•** I'm not sure what do you mean by saying re-evaluating the linq, but you need to read the first quote carefully: *The enumerable object returned by the AsEnumerable method is permanently bound to the DataTable that produced it.*

Comment: @RezaAghaei When testing, I was breaking at the point where the LINQ was re-evaluated.  I hadn't anticipated that the `ListChanged` event would be getting raised _after_ the LINQ was getting re-evaluated.  I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: No problem, I don't have more information to share in the topic. The answer which I posted is all you need and it's completely useful IMO.